# Working on a clock script. I need to add a Zero in front of single digits

Tags: javascript, ajax

As easy as it may sound to a seasoned coder. I am a newbie trying to implement this on my clock page. It can contain errors. The idea is to generate a zero in front of single digits (like "02" instead of "2") for display purposes. It works fine with double digits.
This is what I got, but doesn't do the trick. Includes commented lines of different tries I have done. I would appreciate any input guys.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        getdata();
        myinterval = setInterval(getdata, 30000);

    });

    function getdata(){
        var dt = new Date();
        console.log(dt.getMinutes());
        var myhr = dt.getHours();
        var mymin = dt.getMinutes();
        //if(myhr < 10) myhrstr = '0' + myhr.toString(); else myhrstr = myhr.toString();
        //if(myhr.toString().length < 2) myhrstr = '0' + myhr.toString(); else myhrstr = myhr.toString();
        //if(myhr.toString().length < 2) myhr = "0"+myhr;
        if(myhr.toString().length == 1) myhrstr = "0" + myhr.toString(); else myhrstr = myhr.toString();


        //if(mymin < 10) myminstr = '0' + mymin.toString(); else myminstr = mymin.toString();
        //if(mymin.toString().length < 2) myminstr = '0' + mymin.toString(); else myminstr = mymin.toString();
        //if(mymin.toString().length < 2) mymin = "0"+mymin;
        if(mymin.toString().length == 1) myminstr = "0" + mymin.toString(); else myminstr = mymin.toString();

        var mystr = myhrstr + myminstr;
        $.ajax(
                 {
                 url:"clock.php?action=getdata&dt="+mystr,
                 success:function(result){
                    $('#content').html(result);
                    }   
                }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `str = str.length === 1 ? "0"+str : str`

Comment: Why toString it? Just check if number is less than 10.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think your code isn't working? It works fine.

Here's a demo:

```js
function FakeDate() {
  this.getHours = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 23);
  }
  this.getMinutes = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 59);
  }
}

var dt = new FakeDate(); // use fakeDate for random time generations

var myhr = dt.getHours();
var mymin = dt.getMinutes();
if (myhr.toString().length == 1) myhrstr = "0" + myhr.toString();
else myhrstr = myhr.toString();

if (mymin.toString().length == 1) myminstr = "0" + mymin.toString();
else myminstr = mymin.toString();

var mystr = myhrstr + myminstr;

console.log(mystr);
```

One way you can simplify this code is, since you are not using the numeric values, you can call `toString` right away on the `getHours` and `getMinutes` methods. For the same reason there's also no need for extra variables to hold the string values, you can just use the same variable when appending the `"0"`.

```
// get the strings representing hours and minutes
var myhr = dt.getHours().toString();
var mymin = dt.getMinutes().toString();

// prepend them with zeros if needed
if (myhr.length == 1) myhr = "0" + myhr;
if (mymin.length == 1) mymin = "0" + mymin;

// concatenate them to a 4 digit value
var mystr = myhr + mymin;
```

Here's a demo:

```js
function FakeDate() {
  this.getHours = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 23);
  }
  this.getMinutes = function() {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 59);
  }
}

var dt = new FakeDate(); // use fakeDate for random time generations

// get the strings representing hours and minutes
var myhr = dt.getHours().toString();
var mymin = dt.getMinutes().toString();

// prepend them with zeros if needed
if (myhr.length == 1) myhr = "0" + myhr;
if (mymin.length == 1) mymin = "0" + mymin;

// concatenate them to a 4 digit value
var mystr = myhr + mymin;

console.log(mystr);
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see the code runs well... mine as well as yours, which is much better. However, in practice, it doesn't do the job. Could be my implementation to the page. I'm still trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
var mystr;
if(myhr < 10 ) {
   mystr = "0" + myhr.toString();
} else {
   mystr = myhr.toString();
}
if (mymin < 10) {
    mystr += ":0" + mymin.toString();
} else {
    mystr += ":" + mymin.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple trick to pad single digit with zero

```
('0' + 1).slice(-2) // 01
('0' + 23).slice(-2) // 23
```